# Pymongo .eval() vs. Mongo shell --eval

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, pymongo

What is the equivalent of this command in pymongo using .eval()?

```
mongo localhost/mydb --quiet --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"
```

Because this doesn't seem to work and returns nothing:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient    
client = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
db = client.mydb     
myjs = "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"
print db.eval(myjs)
```

Yes, I understand how `db.collection_names()` works, I specifically need to understand how to correctly pass javascript with `printjson() to pymongo`.eval()` and get the same response back as I would from the original shell command.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are using `printjson()` which is not a JavaScript function. Use `return` instead.

```
In [6]: c = Code("function(){return db.getCollectionNames()}")

In [7]: db.eval(c)
Out[7]: 
['bar',
 'baz',
 'col',
 'collection',
 'demo',
 'first_use',
 'sCriteria',
 'spam',
 'system.indexes',
 'test',
 'v']
```